Not smelling the besamim during havdalah
If they do havdalah in shul after Shabbat and you don’t get a chance to smell the besamim since it’s a big shul, when you get home should you make a bracha again and smell the besamim you have, or should you smell it with no bracha, or is smelling it not even necessary?
Assume when you get home you don’t have to remake havdalah for anyone

You can make a bracha and smell besamim whenever you want. Just like you can say shehakol and drink water whenever you want

@doubleaa the bracha might be different for Ashkenazim depending if it's associated with havdala or not

@Doubleaa the question is should one have to

@Curious Should you have to what? There's a custom to smell spices on regular Saturday nights.
